# is there a way (or conditional statement in Clojure) to go through all different conditions even if one of the conditions is false?

Tags: clojure, conditional-statements

I would like to evaluate all the conditions in this block but i can't find any conditional statement that does this without pulling out when one condition is false. If there's a way outside using conditional statements please let me know also.

Kindly help. Tnx.

```
(when
     ;;when "number" is found in 'a' execute the nextline
      (clojure.string/includes? (.toString a) "number")
        (println (hash-map :num {:test 'number?, :data (flatten num)}))
     ;;when "vector" is found in 'b' execute the nextline
      (clojure.string/includes? (.toString b) "vector")
        (println (hash-map :vec {:test 'vector?, :data vec}))
     ;;when "string" is found in 'c' execute the nextline
      (clojure.string/includes? (.toString c) "symbol")
        (println (hash-map :sym {:test 'symbol?, :data (flatten sym)}) )
     )
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just write it as a sequence of 3 `when` statements.

```
(do   ; it doesn't hurt to wrap in a `do`, but this is usually not needed

  ;when "number" is found in 'a' execute the nextline
  (when (clojure.string/includes? (.toString a) "number")
    (println (hash-map :num {:test 'number?, :data (flatten num)})))

  ;when "vector" is found in 'b' execute the nextline
  (when (clojure.string/includes? (.toString b) "vector")
    (println (hash-map :vec {:test 'vector?, :data vec})))

  ;when "string" is found in 'c' execute the nextline
  (when (clojure.string/includes? (.toString c) "symbol")
    (println (hash-map :sym {:test 'symbol?, :data (flatten sym)}))))
```

As the comment says, wrapping everything in a `do` is possible but probably not needed.

Comment: hello @Alan Thompson thanks but it's same result with what I posted. It breaks if one of the conditions is not satisfied. I tried it without 'do' also and it's same result

Comment: No, what Alan has written here is the clear solution to your problem. If you think it doesn't work, your problem lies in some other code you're not showing us.

Comment: Yeah. Thanks guys. The error was from somewhere else.

Answer (score 1):

If you look at https://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/when you can see that `when` only takes 1 expression and 1 body, which means that only the first check you write will be used as expression and the rest is part of the body.

I am not really sure what you are trying to achieve in your example, but if you want to match with multiple criteria, you can wrap in an `or`.

```
(def a 120)
(when (or (= a 120) (= a 1)) (println "a is 120 or 1"))
```

If you want some kind of keep trying mechanism, then `case`, `cond` or `condp` could be solutions. You can look them up on [ClojureDocs](https://clojuredocs.org/)